# Windows 7 Migrate User Profiles

Tags: windows, windows-7, vbscript

We are trying to create a script to migrate every users profile over in Windows 7 in the case of replacing the PC due to faults etc.

We have been using the following:

```
Dim fso 
Dim oFolder1, objFolder, oFolder
Dim path
Dim colFolders
Dim sDocsAndSettings 
Dim strDirectory

Set fso = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'===========================================================
'CHANGE SDESTINATION FOLDER PATH HERE
sPath =  "C:\Backup"
'===========================================================
Set proFolder = fso.GetFolder(sPath)

'COPY FILES FROM USER PROFILES
sDocsAndSettings = "C:\Users\"   
Set colFolders = fso.GetFolder(sDocsAndSettings) 

For Each oFolder In colFolders.SubFolders
    Select Case LCase(oFolder.Name)
        Case "admin", "administrator", "newuser", "all users", "default user", "default user.original", "localservice", "networkservice"
            'LEAVE THE DEFAULT PROFILES ON THE MACHINE
        Case Else
            'MsgBox oFolder.Name            
            If fso.FolderExists(proFolder) Then
                strDirectory = proFolder & "\" & oFolder.Name 
                If fso.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
                Else 
                    Set objFolder = fso.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
                End If

                'COPY USER PROFILE FOLDERS to Destination Folder
                fso.CopyFolder sDocsAndSettings & oFolder.Name & "\Favorites" , objFolder & "\", True
                fso.CopyFolder sDocsAndSettings & oFolder.Name & "\Documents" , objFolder & "\", True
                fso.CopyFolder sDocsAndSettings & oFolder.Name & "\Desktop" , objFolder & "\", True
            End If
    End Select 
Next

MsgBox "Backup has been completed successfully!"

Set fso = Nothing
```

We seem to have hit an issue that aapears to be with the Junction Points (e.g My Documents) in each profile, which is stopping the script with permission errors, as taking the My Documents line out, the script works. Any ideas, or is there a simpler script to migrate profiles over (we need to be able to migrate specific sub-folders).

Comment: On Error Resume Next turns off vbs error checking. Errors are now in the err object. It's up to you to check err.number and if fixed or ignored clear the error with err.clear.

Answer (score 0):

is the source folder suppose to be `"\My Documents"` ? it might be looking for a file whihc doesn't exists.

```
 fso.CopyFolder sDocsAndSettings & oFolder.Name & "\Documents" , objFolder & "\", True
```

I don't know if this makes a differnce but you can alternatively use the `object.Copy( destination[, overwrite] );` if you set the overwrite to TRUE, this may make sure that ALL files and folders will be overwritten. Can you also explain the permission issues as "is stopping the script with permission error" is a bit vague.

Comment: I have tried with 'My Documents' however still the same permissions error. (Exact error is Permission Denied)

If I turn on show hidden protected files, I cannot access the junction point (shortcut) for my documents, getting permissions denied. However the other 'My Documents' (not a protected/hidden file) opens fine.

Comment: if it works for other folders bar this junction one, then have you checked the security and admin rights on this folder against one that copies successfully?